# pydantic. Add optional field depends on value of another field

Tags: python, json, pydantic

Hi I have to validate this two json
first json

```
{ 'building_type' : 'flat',
  'direction': 'Fake Street',
  'number': 123,
  'apartment': 3
}
```

second json

```
{ 'building_type' : 'house',
  'direction': 'Fake Street',
  'number': 123
}
```

my model

```py
from enum import Enum
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Building(Enum):
  FLAT = 'flat'
  HOUSE = 'house'

class Address(BaseModel):
  model_config = ConfigDict(extra='forbid')
  building_type: Building
  direction: str
```

I need both json examples to be valid. Key 'apartment' will only be provided in case 'building_type' = 'flat'. Is there a way to have field apartment be checked as mandatory only when 'building_type' = 'flat'?